# VPN plugins are not installed

Tags: network-manager, vpn

Trying to configure VPN connection I got a 'VPN plugins are not installed' message. But the network-manager-pptp plugin I need is actually installed. I reinstall it, nothing changed.

How can I fix this?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! First off, I must congratulate you for a great first question! If you have a moment, please take some time to read our [tour] for a better idea of how to maximize the usefulness of our site. It also gives you a free badge, which is cool.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to actually manage the interface from the GUI, you need to install the GUI plugin as well (it ends with `-gnome`).

In your case, this will be the following command:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-pptp-gnome
```

NetworkManager is not just a GUI system. It contains a whole backend as well, which is all manageable from the command-line. The package you installed only enables command-line management of PPTP interfaces.